# Getting bundled extras from a notification reliever intent to a started activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a notification receiver that is being called from my alarm.

The notification receiver bundles the data for a new intent (activity) and starts it like this:

```
// Create an in intent to go to the new alarm video
Intent repeatingAlarmIntent = new Intent(context,RepeatingAlarmActivity.class);

// Bundle the videoID the alarm has the correct video to open
Bundle alarmExtras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("AlarmVidId", VideoId);
repeatingAlarmIntent.putExtras(alarmExtras);

// Set the flags for the alarm intent
repeatingAlarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    repeatingAlarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

// Start the alarm intent
context.startActivity(repeatingAlarmIntent);
```

In the new activity when I try to retrieve the bundled data it is null, this is how I am attempting to retrieve the bundled data:

```
public class RepeatingAlarmActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    String VideoId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        VideoId= intent.getStringExtra("AlarmVidId");
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all with the following:

```
Intent repeatingAlarmIntent = new Intent(context,RepeatingAlarmActivity.class);
repeatingAlarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmVidId", VideoId);
repeatingAlarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
repeatingAlarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(repeatingAlarmIntent);
```

Your problem is you created a `Bundle` called `alarmExtras` however you are putting the extra field in the variable called `extra`.

There is no need to create `Bundle`. just add the value directly to the `Intent`.

Also, you are doing `setFlags()`. If you need more than one, do `addFlags()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your `extras` variable when calling putString does not match the `alarmExtras` are adding to the Intent.

```
Bundle alarmExtras = new Bundle();
alarmExtras.putString("AlarmVidId", VideoId);   
repeatingAlarmIntent.putExtras(alarmExtras);
```

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for your response. So the variable name you set it to has to be the same on both sides? I changed VideoId on  both sides and it is still the same. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I have edited my question so all the variable names are the same as I tried with your solution. In case I understood you incorrectly.

Comment: Yep I checked that

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution.

I am pretty sure it is because of the lifecycle of the notification receiver and the context.

So  instead of using the context that was passed when started the receiver I used that context to get the application context.

This method is working but I welcome comments on potential problems with this method as I have never had to solve something like this before.

This is what worked for me:

```
// Create an in intent to go to the new alarm video
Intent repeatingAlarmIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),RepeatingAlarmActivity.class);

// Bundle the videoID the alarm has the correct video to open
Bundle alarmExtras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("AlarmVidId", VideoId);
repeatingAlarmIntent.putExtras(alarmExtras);

// Set the flags for the alarm intent
repeatingAlarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    repeatingAlarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

// Start the alarm intent
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(repeatingAlarmIntent);
```

Above when creating the intent and starting the intent there is now:

```
getApplicationContext()
```

On the activity side were no changes required.